# Selecting Rows with based on Count (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite

Hoping for some help with this:

1) I am trying to select all calls (rows) for CustomerIDs that show up 6 or more times within a 30 day rolling period, so if the CustomerID is within the file 6 or more times within 30 days, then it would provide me with all records for that CustomerID.

2) I also need to select all calls for CustomerIDs that show up 2 or more times within a 30 day rolling period but ONLY if two certain columns also match (CallType1 and CallType2). Very similar to the query with the 6 calls but we need to consider that the call types are exactly the same too.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM tablename
    WHERE "CustomerID" 
    IN ('MyProgram'));
```

The query above selects all of the CustomerIDs which reach my program. I need to add the logic to count >=6 CustomerIDs (item 1 above) and then a second query to get the >=2 with the same CallTypes.

Answer (score 0):

The innermost subquery computes how many calls there are in the window beginning at `First`.
The middle subquery checks this value for every possible window in the table. (This is inefficient, but SQLite has no window functions.)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID
                     FROM TableName AS First
                     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM TableName
                            WHERE Date BETWEEN      First.Date
                                           AND date(First.Date, '+30 days')
                              AND CustomerID = First.CustomerID
                           ) >= 6)
```

This assumes that there is a column `Date` using the default date format (`yyyy-mm-dd`).

Comment: The second question is left as an exercise. You should post a single question per question anyway.